# Multiple environments (Staging, QA, production, etc) with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

What is considered a good practice with K8S for managing multiple environments (QA, Staging, Production, Dev, etc)?

As an example, say that a team is working on a product which requires deploying a few APIs, along with a front-end application. Usually, this will require at least 2 environments:

- Staging: For iterations/testing and validation before releasing to the client
- Production: This the environment the client has access to. Should contain stable and well-tested features.

So, assuming the team is using Kubernetes, what would be a good practice to host these environments? This far we've considered two options:

1. Use a K8s cluster for each environment
2. Use only one K8s cluster and keep them in different namespaces.

(1) Seems the safest options since it minimizes the risks of potential human mistake and machine failures, that could put the production environment in danger. However, this comes with the cost of more master machines and also the cost of more infrastructure management.

(2) Looks like it simplifies infrastructure and deployment management because there is one single cluster but it raises a few questions like:

- How does one make sure that a human mistake might impact the production environment?
- How does one make sure that a high load in the staging environment won't cause a loss of performance in the production environment?

There might be some other concerns, so I'm reaching out to the K8s community on StackOverflow to have a better understanding of how people are dealing with these sort of challenges.

Comment: How did you end up doing this? Please could you let us know... I am also learning and trying to work out the best way. Sounds like setting up separate clusters is probably the right way to go...

Comment: We ended up having two clusters, one for staging and another one for production. There is an extra management over head from an infrastructure point of view but in our case the isolation level was worth it.

Comment: @YoanisGil is there an answer here you can mark as accepted?

Comment: @tdensmore most answers are good in their own way. The thing is, there is just not one answer and it depends on the use case in question. I think K8s and its community have matured a lot since I first asked this question (almost 3 years now) and there seems to be at least some minimal best practices that one could apply, regardless of how many clusters are used and for what purpose (I'm thinking namespaces, network policies, node selectors, seccomp, etc).

Answer (score 68):

### Multiple Clusters Considerations

Take a look at this blog post from Vadim Eisenberg (*IBM / Istio*): [Checklist: pros and cons of using multiple Kubernetes clusters, and how to distribute workloads between them](http://vadimeisenberg.blogspot.com/2019/03/multicluster-pros-and-cons.html).

I'd like to highlight some of the pros/cons:

> **Reasons to have multiple clusters**
>
> - Separation of production/development/test: especially for testing a    new version of Kubernetes, of a service mesh, of other cluster software
> - Compliance: according to some regulations some applications must run in separate clusters/separate VPNs
> - Better isolation for security
> - Cloud/on-prem: to split the load between on-premise services
>
> **Reasons to have a single cluster**
>
> - Reduce setup, maintenance and administration overhead
> - Improve utilization
> - Cost reduction

Considering a not too expensive environment, with average maintenance, and yet still ensuring security isolation for production applications, I would recommend:

- 1 cluster for DEV and STAGING (separated by namespaces, *maybe even isolated, using Network Policies, like in [Calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/calico-network-policy-comes-to-kubernetes/)*)
- 1 cluster for PROD

### Environment Parity

It's a [good practice](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) to keep development, staging, and production as similar as possible:

> Differences between backing services mean that tiny incompatibilities
> crop up, causing code that worked and passed tests in development or
> staging to fail in production. These types of errors create friction
> that disincentivizes continuous deployment.

**Combine a powerful CI/CD tool with [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm)**. You can use the flexibility of [helm values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/#helm) to set default configurations, just overriding the configs that differ from an environment to another.

[GitLab CI/CD with AutoDevops](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/) has a powerful integration with Kubernetes, which allows you to manage multiple Kubernetes clusters already with helm support.

### [Managing multiple clusters](https://medium.com/@eduardobaitello/using-different-kubectl-versions-with-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-a3ad8707b87b) *(`kubectl` interactions)*

> When you are working with multiple Kubernetes clusters, it’s easy to
> mess up with contexts and run `kubectl` in the wrong cluster. Beyond
> that, Kubernetes has [restrictions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew) for versioning mismatch between the
> client (`kubectl`) and server (kubernetes master), so running commands
> in the right context does not mean running the right client version.

To overcome this:

- Use [`asdf`](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) to manage multiple `kubectl` versions
- [Set the `KUBECONFIG`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable) env var to change between multiple `kubeconfig` files
- Use [`kube-ps1`](https://github.com/jonmosco/kube-ps1) to keep track of your current context/namespace
- Use [`kubectx` and `kubens`](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) to change fast between clusters/namespaces
- Use aliases to combine them all together

I have an article that exemplifies how to accomplish this: [Using different kubectl versions with multiple Kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/@eduardobaitello/using-different-kubectl-versions-with-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-a3ad8707b87b)

I also recommend the following reads:

- [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://medium.com/@ahmetb/mastering-kubeconfig-4e447aa32c75) by Ahmet Alp Balkan (*Google Engineer*)
- [How Zalando Manages 140+ Kubernetes Clusters](https://srcco.de/posts/how-zalando-manages-140-kubernetes-clusters.html) by Henning Jacobs (*Zalando Tech*)

Comment: Is it possible to handle multiple configurations without using Helm? kubectl doesn't have a way to compose configuration files (for example to override the differences between dev/prod)?

Answer (score 29):

Definitely use a separate cluster for development and creating docker images so that your staging/production clusters can be locked down security wise. Whether you use separate clusters for `staging + production` is up to you to decide based on risk/cost - certainly keeping them separate will help avoid `staging` affecting `production`.

I'd also highly recommend using GitOps to promote versions of your apps between your environments.

To minimise human error I also recommend you look into automating as much as you can for your CI/CD and promotion.

Here's [a demo of how to automate CI/CD with multiple environments on Kubernetes using GitOps](https://jenkins-x.io/docs/resources/demos-talks-posts/devoxx-uk-2018/) for promotion between environments and Preview Environments on Pull Requests which was done live on GKE though Jenkins X supports most kubernetes clusters

Comment: link seems to be broken

Comment: I believe that this is the talk in question, though I've not edited the original answer in case I'm wrong! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BF3MhFjvBTU

Answer (score 24):

It depends on what you want to test in each of the scenarios. In general I would try to avoid running test scenarios on the production cluster to avoid unnecessary side effects (performance impact, etc.).

If your intention is testing with a staging system that *exactly mimics the production system* I would recommend firing up an exact replica of the complete cluster and shut it down after you're done testing and move the deployments to production.

If your purpose is testing a staging system that allows *testing the application* to deploy I would run a smaller staging cluster permanently and update the deployments (with also a scaled down version of the deployments) as required for continuous testing.

To control the different clusters I prefer having a separate ci/cd machine that is not part of the cluster but used for firing up and shutting down clusters as well as performing deployment work, initiating tests, etc. This allows to set up and shut down clusters as part of automated testing scenarios.

Comment: This is still up for debate but I found this discussion helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/GPaGOGxCDD8

Comment: I upvoted for mentioning the two types of staging environments.

Answer (score 12):

Unless compliance or other requirements dictate otherwise, I favor a single cluster for all environments. With this approach, attention points are:

- Make sure you also group nodes per environment using labels. You can then use the `nodeSelector` on resources to ensure that they are running on specific nodes. This will reduce the chances of (excess) resource consumption spilling over between environments.
- Treat your namespaces as subnets and forbid all egress/ingress traffic by default. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/.
- Have a strategy for managing service accounts. `ClusterRoleBindings` imply something different if a clusters hosts more than one environment.
- Use scrutiny when using tools like Helm. Some charts blatantly install service accounts with cluster-wide permissions, but permissions to service accounts should be limited to the environment they are in.

Comment: How can you plan for cluster upgradation  failure?

Answer (score 11):

It's clear that by keeping the production cluster appart from the staging one, the risk of potential errors impacting the production services is reduced. However this comes at a cost of more infrastructure/configuration management, since it requires at least:

- at least 3 masters for the production cluster and at least one master for the staging one
- 2  Kubectl config files to be added to the CI/CD system

Let’s also not forget that there could be more than one environment. For example I've worked at companies where there are at least 3 environments:

- QA: This where we did daily deploys and where we did our internal QA before releasing to the client)
- Client QA: This where we deployed before deploying to production so that the client could validate the environment before releasing to production)
- Production: This where production services are deployed.

I think ephemeral/on-demand clusters makes sense but only for certain use cases (load/performance testing or very « big » integration/end-to-end testing) but for more persistent/sticky environments I see an overhead that might be reduced by running them within a single cluster.

I guess I wanted to reach out to the k8s community to see what patterns are used for such scenarios like the ones I've described.

Comment: why do you need ` at least one master for the staging one`? do you mean to use micro-kubernetes like k3s? I upvoted you

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a middle point. I am working with eks and node groups. The master is managed, scaled and maintained by aws. You could then create 3 kinds of node groups (just an example):

1 - General Purpose -> labels: environment=general-purpose

2 - Staging -> labels: environment=staging (taints if necessary)

3 - Prod -> labels: environment=production (taints if necessary)

You can use tolerations and node selectors on the pods so they are placed where they are supposed to be.

This allows you to use more robust or powerful nodes for production's nodegroups, and, for example, SPOT instances for staging, uat, qa, etc... and has a couple of big upsides:

- Environments are physically separated (and virtually too, in namespaces)
- You can  reduce costs by sharing not only the masters, but also some nodes with pods shared by the two environments and by using spot or cheaper instances in staging/uat/...
- No cluster-management overheads

You have to pay attention to roles and policies to keep it secure. You can implement network policies using, for example eks+calico.

Update:

I found a doc that may be useful when using EKS. It has some details on how to safely run multi-tenant cluster, and some of this details may be useful to isolate production pods and namespaces from the ones in staging.

https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/multitenancy/

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts here:

1. Do not trust namespaces to protect the cluster from catastrophe. Having separate production and non-prod (dev,stage,test,etc) clusters is the minimum necessary requirement. Noisy neighbors have been known to [bring down entire clusters](https://k8s.af/).
2. Separate repositories for code and k8s deployments (Helm, Kustomize, etc.) will make best practices like [trunk-based development and feature-flagging](https://codefresh.io/blog/stop-using-branches-deploying-different-gitops-environments/) easier as the teams scale.
3. Using Environments as a Service (EaaS) will allow each PR to be tested in its own short-lived (ephemeral) environment. Each environment is a high-fidelity copy of production (including custom infrastructure like database, buckets, dns, etc.), so devs can remotely code against a trustworthy environment (NOT minikube). This can help reduce configuration drift, improve release cycles, and improve the overall dev experience. (disclaimer: I work for an EaaS company).

Comment: I want to stress the value of this answer, and especially link #2. We were using the traditional dev/test/prod git model until reading this... it was a nightmare. Turns out we were using Helm and Kustomize all wrong! The link in #2 above, as well as its follow on link at the bottom of the article, were tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Using multiple clusters is the norm, at the very least to enforce a strong separation between production and "non-production".

In that spirit, do note that [GitLab 13.2 (July 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/07/22/gitlab-13-2-released/#multiple-kubernetes-cluster-deployment-in-core) now includes:

> ### Multiple Kubernetes cluster deployment in Core

> Using GitLab to deploy multiple Kubernetes clusters with GitLab previously required a Premium license.
> Our community spoke, and we listened: deploying to multiple clusters is useful even for individual contributors.
> **Based on your feedback, starting in GitLab 13.2, you can deploy to multiple group and project clusters in Core.**

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_2/MultipleProjectClusters.png]

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#multiple-kubernetes-clusters) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212229).

Answer (score 0):

I think running a single cluster make sense because it reduces overhead, monitoring. But, you have to make sure to place network policies, access control in place.

Network policy - to prohibit dev/qa environment workload to interact with prod/staging stores.

Access control - who have access on different environment resources using ClusterRoles, Roles etc..

Comment: Using a single cluster for multiple environments is an anti-pattern. Doing so is a great recipe for big problems (especially if it contains production workloads).