# Is it possible to deploy a cluster with one service running locally?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Say you have 3 or more services that communicate with each other constantly, if they are deployed remotely to the same cluster all is good cause they can see each other.

However, I was wondering how could I deploy one of those locally, using minikube for instance, in a way that they are still able to talk to each other.

I am aware that I can port-forward the other two so that the one I have locally deployed can send calls to the others but I am not sure how I could make it work for the other two also be able to send calls to the local one.

Comment: Your local service will not be discoverable by a remote service unless you have a direct IP.   One other way is to establish RTC or Web socket connection between your local and remote services using an external server.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR Yes, it is possible but not recommended, it is difficult and comes with a security risk.**

[Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4185234/charlie) wrote very well in the comment and is absolutely right:

> Your local service will not be discoverable by a remote service unless you have a direct IP. One other way is to establish RTC or Web socket connection between your local and remote services using an external server.

As you can see, it is possible, but also not recommended. Generally, both containerization and the use of kubernetes tend to isolate environments. If you want your services to communicate with each other anyway being in completely different clusters on different machines, you need to configure the appropriate network connections over the public internet. It also may come with a security risk.

If you want to set up the environment locally, it will be a much better idea to run these 3 services as an independent whole. Also take into account that the Minikube is mainly designed for learning and testing certain solutions and is not entirely suitable for production solutions.

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified that. The intent here is for testing, the real scenario would have a number of services that makes it impractical to spin all up locally. But there is still the need to test a specific change, debug it and such, using a local environment for the changed service and a remote environment for the services that remain the same as production.

Comment: It would therefore be even more difficult to create it the way you described it. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212836/multiple-environments-staging-qa-production-etc-with-kubernetes

The best solution for you is to create several environments, e.g. dev, prod and stage. Then you can go ahead and test new changes.